# Start time gets updated every-time app is launch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

Requirement - *App needs to be logged out everyday at specific time irrespective of whether app is in background or foregound.*

Solution - *Run a snippet every day to logout user from the app. **WorkManager** has periodic work with initial delay which can be set at specific time and runs periodically.*

Issue - ***schedule_requested_at*** is updated every time app is launched available under ***WorkSpec*** table. Though ***initial_delay*** remains the same. Used App Inspection to view Database.

Same can be visible under ***App Inspection > Background Task Inspector > Worker*** > LogOutWorker > Start updated every-time app is launched.

Tried

- We have added a flag in preferences to check that we are not updating worker again. Though we are not setting it again. Which can be known from ***initial_delay*** is constant in the table.

Following is the set-up we are using for workManager.

- We are using `PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder` with `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork`

```
val refreshWork = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<LogOutWorker>(
            interval.toLong(), TimeUnit.HOURS
        ).setInitialDelay(minutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .addTag(tag)
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(tag, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, refreshWork)
```

- Removing workManager initialization from manifest.

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove">
</provider>
```

- We have added initialisation in the app with basic log enables only.

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

@Inject
lateinit var logoutWorkerFactory: LogOutWorkerFactory

override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
  WorkManager.initialize(this, workManagerConfiguration)
}

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
        return Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(logoutWorkerFactory)
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
            .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: The field `schedule_requested_at ` is for an internal reference regarding an issue on API levels below 23 with `AlarmManager`, which is also documented in the `WorkSpec#scheduleRequestedAt`. Changes in the field would not change the timings of the Worker (depending on the OS) until you use `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP`.

Comment: @DarShan Thank you for adding that information. I have been testing it in Android 11 which is at API 30. So it should not be reset in that case. Nevertheless, I have to test it with small frequency to see if I should be worry with that `schedule_requested_at` or not.

Comment: No, you should not be worried about the `schedule_requested_at` flag. If you dig deeper into the documentation, you'll see it is updated frequently so as to make sure that the work is not enqueued twice, the column's default value is `-1` (`WorkSpec.scheduleRequestedAt`) which means it needs to be enqueued. The reference can be found in the `WorkSpecDao#getEligibleWorkForScheduling` method.